# CentOS FreeRadius and WPA 2 Enterprise

Tags: radius

It is to my knowledge that as I finished setup my FreeRadius on my CentOS server, I point my router to the server and all is done.

Any user will need to use WPA2-Enterprise to login.

I previously used DAC to authenticate my user, after setting up RADIUS, do I no longer need a web page like how DAC need, right? The login form will be presented on the users device OS, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking a lot, this is what I know.

DAC Authentication is controller-based, and as I used local database for authentication check, changing it to RADIUS will still require that webpage to be present.

In order to switch to WPA2-Enterprise, I need to configure each and every access point to use WPA2-Enterprise, and point them to the RADIUS server. That's mainly because I use Fat APs, if the access points I have in my environment are thin APs, they can simply fetch configuration from my controller.